A movie about a man obsessed with Pamela Anderson
It's a movie about a man who comes to America in the early 90's. It was released in summer 2006 and the main character had an obsession with Pamela Anderson Lee  and watches her do porn in the movies and watches her on Baywatch.
He seems to come from an Arab country? Could you please help me find this movie? He is also going to hotel rooms and gets himself ready for appointments or something and he doesn't shower.

I find it fascinating that this is at least the second time a British Jew pretending to be a Kazakh has been mistaken for an Arab, the first time being documented in the film Borat itself, where a man at the rodeo advises him to shave his moustache because it makes him "look Arab".

How can one forget Borat (2006)? ;)

Borat Sagdiyev [Sacha Baron Cohen] struggles to make a living in Kazakhstan as a TV reporter amidst well known beliefs that his country's economy suffers because of Jews. He is selected by his Government to travel to the United States of America and submit a report on its society and culture, to which he agrees. Accordingly, he and his producer Azamat Bagatov set out to experience America first-hand. Both then attempt to learn the American culture and proper etiquette, especially when using the restroom and the elevator. While doing so, Borat watches Baywatch and falls hopelessly in love with Pamela Anderson.

It was part comedy, part documentary. Here's the trailer:



